# Python object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

Any ideas on why this code doesn't work?
I keep getting an error

```
def boxCheck(number1,number2,number3):
    if number1 * number2 * number3 == 0 or number1 < 0 or number2 < 0 or number3 < 0:
        return False
    else:
        numbers = [number1, number2, number3]
        sortedNumbers = numbers.sort()
        trial1 = number1 * number2 * number3
        trial2 = sortedNumbers[1] * sortedNumbers[1]
        if trial1 == trial2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

boxCheck(4,16,8)
```

Comment: Don't just say "I keep getting an error", show the error. Copy it and paste it here, with the exact text, traceback, etc. In this case, the problem was pretty obvious, but often it isn't—and the traceback (which would tell us you specifically had a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`, and that it was specifically on that `sortedNumbers[1]`) is the only way to get started debugging it.

Answer (score 5):

What happens is that [`sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) *sorts* the list *in-place* so it doesn't return anything (in fact, it returns `None`), therefore the variable `sortedNumbers` will be `None`.

**What can you do?** You can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), which will return the sorted list:

```
sortedNumbers = sorted(numbers)
```

**Note:** Don't forget to print your results:

```
print(boxCheck(4,16,8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the manual says about the sort method:

```
> Help on method_descriptor:
> 
> sort(...)
>     L.sort(cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) -- stable sort *IN PLACE*;
>     cmp(x, y) -> -1, 0, 1
```

Your statement

```
sortedNumbers = numbers.sort()
```

results in nothing being saved to sortedNumbers.